# Behavior of post increment in cout

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

main(){

int i = 5;

cout << i++ << i--<< ++i << --i << i << endl;


}
```

The above program compiled with g++ gives output :

```
45555
```

While the following program:

```
int x=20,y=35;

x =y++ + y + x++ + y++;

cout << x<< endl << y;
```

gives result as

```
126

37
```

Can anyone please explain the output.

Comment: *"Behavior of post increment in prinf"* You're not using `printf`. You're using I/O streams.

Answer (score 13):

```
cout << i++ << i--
```

is semantically equivalent to

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, i++),   i--);
           <------arg1--------->, <-arg2->
```

> $1.9/15- "When calling a function
>   (whether or not the function is
>   inline), every value computation and
>   side effect associated with any
>   argument expression, or with the
>   postfix expression designating the
>   called function, is sequenced before
>   execution of every expression or
>   statement in the body of the called
>   function. [ **Note: Value computations
>   and side effects associated with
>   different argument expressions are
>   unsequenced. —end note** ]

C++0x:

This means that the evaluation of the arguments arg1/arg2 are unsequenced (neither of them is sequenced before the other).

The same section in the draft Standard also states,

> If a side effect on a scalar object is
>   unsequenced relative to either another
>   side effect on the same scalar object
>   or a value computation using the value
>   of the same scalar object, the
>   behavior is undefined.

Now there is a sequence point at the semicolon at the end of the full expression below

```
operator<<(operator<<(cout, i++), i--);
                                      ^ the interesting sequence point is right here
```

As is clear, evaluation of both arg1 and arg2 lead to side effect on the scalar variable 'i', and as we saw above, the side effects are unsequenced.

Therefore the code has undefined behavior. So what does that mean?

Here is how 'undefined behavior' is defined :) in the Standard.

> Permissible undefined behavior ranges
>   from ignoring the situation completely
>   with unpredictable results, to
>   behaving during translation or program
>   execution in a documented manner
>   characteristic of the environment
>   (with or without the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message), to terminating a
>   translation or execution (with the
>   issuance of a diagnostic message).
>   Many erroneous program constructs do
>   not engender undefined behavior; they
>   are required to be diagnosed.

Do you see correlation with @DarkDust's response 'The compiler is even allowed to set your computer on fire :-)'

So any output you get from such a code is really in the dreaded realm of undefined behavior.

Don't do it.

Only thing that is `defined` about such code is that it helps OP and many of us get lots of votes (if answered correctly) :)

Answer (score 4):

The result of the second program's expression is undefined. The compiler is even allowed to set your computer on fire :-) You're not allowed to modify a variable twice within one sequence point (in this case: from `=` to `;`).

**Edit:**

For detailed explanations, see [the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=expr), specifically [question 3.2](http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html).

Comment: *"You're not allowed to modify a variable twice within one sequence point"* You're saying that `x =y++ + y + x++ + y++;` is invalid in some way?

Comment: T.J. Crowder> yes. even x = x++ is invalid.

Comment: @Yossarian: Yeah, I just saw the `x++` (I thought he was talking about the `y++` stuff). Surprised it's invalid. *Useless*, but I'm surprised by "invalid." (BTW: If you put an `@` at the beginning of a reply to a comment giving the user's name, it'll notify them they have a comment. E.g., `@T.J. Crowder:` rather than `T.J. Crowder>`)

Comment: @T.J.: Yes, it's invalid. For detailed explanations, see [the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=expr).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Even removing the `x++` that is still UB as there are two `y++` with no sequence points in between.

Comment: @DarkDust and David: Thanks. I was never crazy enough to do it, had never run into that. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other's answers:

If you are using `g++`, using the `-Wsequence-point` option tells that:

```
$ g++ -Wsequence-point a.cpp
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:8: warning: operation on ‘i’ may be undefined
                                          ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yet another reason to use warnings. Yet another.

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behaviour, so anything could happen