# Behaviour of Pre-increment and Post increment in C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Behavior of post increment in cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986361/behavior-of-post-increment-in-cout)

```
//Increment Decrement
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int a=5,b=6;

cout<<++a<<a++<<++a<<++a<<++a;

return 0;

}
```

My expected output should be 108876 but g++ compiler shows the output as 108101010

Comment: This is undefined behavior. http://ideone.com/450kh

Comment: Remove the C tag. This question has nothing to do with C since it depends on operator overloading and the sequence point semantics of overloaded operators.

Comment: "Unspecified behavior", right?

Comment: Ah, it's been what, three days since the last `++i++` question?

Answer (score 2):

It is an Undefined Behavior. So we cannot define that behavior for you.

Comment: "Unspecified behavior", right?

Comment: But there should be some rules on which the post increement and preincrement runs.... Are you implying that it has not defined in g++ compiler?

Comment: @user278092: This is undefined behavior because an object is getting modified more than once without an intervening sequence point.

Comment: @John: An Specifed behavior leads to an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Als: Not really. The order of argument evaluation for a function call is unspecified, but it doesn't lead to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is specifically called out in the standard as "all bets are off, even for before the undefined behavior occurs." Unspecified behavior adds indeterminism for a limited scope.

Answer (score 2):

As others will doubtlessly point out, you have undefined behavior, so
you really shouldn't expect anything.  But I'm curious where you derived
your "expected behavior" from.  If the behavior were determined (e.g. as
it is in Java), I would expect something like `668910`.

Comment: Indeed, this is what I "expected".

Comment: Nobody expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Comment: A good (but perverse) compiler could recognize such things, and do something disagreeable.  Say like sending email to the programmer's boss complaining about the quality of the code.