# Why can a pointer not point to post increment but can do that to pre increment?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    int x=7;
    int *p=&x;
    int *p1=&++x;
    int *p2=&x++;
    int *p3=&(++x);
    int *p4=&(x++);
    cout<<p<<endl<<p1<<endl<<p2<<endl<<p3<<endl<<p4<<endl<<*p<<endl<<*p++<<endl<<*++p<<endl<<*(p++)<<endl<<*(++p)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

p2 and p4 return error. Also, can you please explain the dereferencing of all the increments of the pointer, p, that I print in the cout statement?

Comment: When asking questions about error, share the error as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post-increment and Pre-increment concept?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445706/post-increment-and-pre-increment-concept)

Comment: Hint: consider which increment operators return the original x and which make a copy to be returned.

Comment: And the strange output is because of this [Behavior of post increment in cout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986361/behavior-of-post-increment-in-cout)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not the pointers. It's the action of taking addresses of variables (on the RHS of the assignment operations).

The operator `&` can only be used on [**lvalue**s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#lvalue). When you post-increment a variable, the value of the expression is an [**rvalue**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue), which is not eligible to be taken address.

Reference from CppReference (linked above):

> #### lvalue
>
> - `++a` and `--a`, the built-in pre-increment and pre-decrement expressions;
>
> #### prvalue
>
> - `a++` and `a--`, the built-in post-increment and post-decrement expressions;

And below:

> #### lvalue
>
> Properties:
>
> - Address of an lvalue may be taken: **`&++i`** and `&std::endl` are valid expressions.
>
> #### rvalue
>
> - Address of an rvalue may not be taken: `&int()`, **`&i++`**, `&42`, and `&std::move(x)` are invalid