# Why does my post increment operator overload not work in a cout stream?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I am trying to create a new `uint24_t` type for use on my embedded device. All functionality appears to work *except* when I use the type in an output stream.

I thought this might be an issue with not overloading the `<<` operator however I tried this with `friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &out, const uint24_t b) { out << (uint32_t) b.val; return out; }` and it still yielded the same results

```
#include <iostream>

struct uint24_t
{
private:
    uint32_t val;

public:
    uint24_t() {}

    uint24_t(const uint32_t& a) {
        val = a;
        val &= 0x00FFFFFF;
    }

    uint24_t(const uint24_t& a) {
        val = a.val;
    }

    operator uint32_t() const {
        return val;
    }

    uint24_t operator++(int) {
        uint24_t temp = val;
        val = val + 1;
        val &= 0x00FFFFFF;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    uint24_t var;

    // Test post incrementor in ostream for uint24_t
    var = 0;
    std::cout << std::hex << var++ << " " << var << std::endl; // Outputs 0 0  (should be 0 1)
    std::cout << std::hex << var << std::endl;                    // Outputs expected 1

    // Test post incrementor in isolation for uint24_t
    var = 0;
    uint32_t temp = (var++) + (var);
    std::cout << std::hex << temp << std::endl; // Outputs expected 1
}
```

I expect the output of `std::cout << std::hex << uint24++ << " " << uint24 << std::endl;` to be `0 1` however I actually get `0 0`

Comment: Probably because of undefined behavior. More on the subject in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986361/behavior-of-post-increment-in-cout).

Comment: "`// Outputs 0 0  (should be 0 1)`" You are under the false assumption that operands are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what is going on. Clang produces the "expected" output. Shame GCC doesn't pick up on it with `-Wsequence-point`